# JS newbie needs help with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a jquery function but am brand new to jquery.  Here is my very simple function, which I want to clear all of the links to the unselected class, except for the selected link:

```
$(function() 
{
    $('li a').click(function()
    {
        $('li a').addClass('unselected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');


    });


});
```

How do I do this?  And then how do I deselect all of the ones except for those with a specific name attribute? Here is an example of a link:

```
<li><a id="106" name="wavelength" href="#">10.6 &micro;</a></li>... set of links
```

and another set of links

```
<li><a id="10watt" name="power" href="#">10 watt</a></li>....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment on one of the other answers (which is now deleted):

> These li a tags are in five columns. How do I deselect only the ones in the column, while leaving the others selected? I have tagged with my links with name attributes to group them

You could group your `<li>` links by the `<ul>` they are contained in!

You can use jQuery to search the `<a>`'s parents for the [`.closest('ul')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) then [`.find('li a')`](http://api.jquery.com/find) within that:

```
// best practice says you should cache the result of this search 
// so you don't need to find it again
var $links = $('li a');
// attach a click function to the links
$links.click(function() {
  // again cache it... we will use it more than once.
  var $this = $(this); 

  // remove selected from everything - add unselected
  $this.closest('ul').find('li a').removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');
  // remove unselected from this link and add selected
  $this.removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});
```

Since you said the link groups share a `name` attribute take a look at this code:

```
var $links = $('li a');
$links.click(function() {
  // store ourself as a jquery object, and get our name:
  var $this = $(this), myname = $this.attr('name');

  // filter $links to obtain the ones that share myname:
  $links.filter(function() {
    // we can use the DOM element "this.name" instead of $(this).attr('name')
    // to save some time here:
    return this.name == myname;
  }).removeClass('selected').addClass('unselected');

  $this.removeClass('unselected').addClass('selected');
});
```

As far as finding one with a particular name attribute check out the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) which looks like this:

```
$('li a[name=wavelength]');
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is a brand new area for me, so I have no clue what I am doing.  I hate having others write my code for me, but until I see code I can't learn, right?  Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  var $a = $('li a');
  $a.click(function() {
    $a.removeClass('selected').not(this).addClass('unselected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

If you want to target links with a specific name, one of the possible selectors is 
`a[name='somenamehere']`. 
In the example, this would suffice:
`$a.filter("[name='somenamehere']")`
*(You might want to implement the attribute selector differently, depending on what you want to do)*

Also, it might be a good idea if you did away with the "unselected" class. I assume you are using it for styling.  If so, give all the links a style, then give .selected links styling on top of their original style:

```
.menu a, .menu a:visited {
  color: #FF0000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there... :) Try this:

```
    $(function()  
{ 
    $('li a').click(function() 
    { 
        $("li a[name!='wavelength']").addClass('unselected'); 
                $(this).removeClass('unselected'); 
                $(this).addClass('selected'); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Cybermate.  How do I generalize this, so I can column by column only select one item in each column?

Comment: Hey Shummel, I did not understand what does column by column mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There are five columns horizontally.  The user chooses an item from column 1 and then column 2 and so on.  But gnarf's answer got me where I wanted.  Thanks for being so willing to help.